# Can i define an index on doc schema for an array property in mongoose.js

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have the following Document Schema in mongoose2.4.8 running on node0.4.12:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  following: [{type: ObjectId, ref: 'User'}],
  followers: [{type: ObjectId, ref: 'User'}]
});
```

I want to speed up the lookup in the these arrays. Can i use mongoose.js index functionality? And how?

Comment: @DeaDEnD what i am trying to do is to find whether user x is following   user y. This implies a lookup in either one of the arrays. Is it faster if define another schema specifically for the following functionality, something like: `var FollowerSchema = new Schema({follower: {type:ObjectId, ref: 'User', index:true }, followed: {type:ObjectId, ref: 'User', index: true} });`

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to lookup the ObjectId in the arrays? Or are you looking for the User? If the latter, add the index on the User Schema.

Comment: I'm trying to lookup the ObjectIds in the arrays. But the functionality i'm after is finding followers/following users as fast as possible

Comment: In that case you don't want to add an index there because what that would do is make searches for ObjectIds, not users, in the array faster. By default, an index is already adaded to the `_id` field of a schema so you won't even need to add it yourself.